# Disable SQL Login for Specific Application and Windows User

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, security

I have an SQL Server 2008 installation running as a back end for an application.

I want to stop a certain terminal user accessing the DB as SA from SSMS but allow them to make changes through the application when logged in as SA.
I don't have the option of using a different user in SQL as the application allows only certain functions when `user = 'SA'`.

I want to do something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LOGONREJECT
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    IF (inserted.User = 'sa'
    AND inserted.ApplicationName LIKE 'SQL Server Management Studio%'
    AND inserted.WorkStationName = 'TerminalServerName')
        ROLLBACK
END
```

Is there any way to do this, preferably via a security setting but if not via a trigger similar to the above?

Comment: First, you should never use the `sa` login for applications, ever. And even sysadmins shouldn't need to use it for their work. Second, have you looked at [application roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998(v=sql.100).aspx)? They are intended for this scenario where a user should have different permissions when using a specific application.

Comment: I know never to use sa in an application, I have no control over the application and can't stop the use of the sa login. Application roles look interesting but can they be used to specify what machine can/cannot access?

Comment: If you have no control over the application then you probably can't use an application role, because you have to code the application to use it. The server can gather some information about the client from system functions but you can't trust it (e.g. see the docs for [`HOST_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598(v=sql.100).aspx)). But if you can't control the application and you can't control the use of the `sa` login then there's no point in even trying to restrict access anyway.